# How to find templates that use some specific field type?

Tags: fieldtype, custom-field

I need to find all templates that use a defined field type.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As field types are not linked with item's `ID` you cannot use Link Database for that.

### PowerShell

You could iterate through all fields in PowerShell and find those with particular field type 
[image]

### SQL

Open SQL Management studio
Execute something like that

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [ItemId]
    ,[FieldId]
    ,[Value]
    ,[Created]
    ,[Updated]
FROM [sc_sitecore_master].[dbo].[SharedFields]
WHERE FieldId = '{AB162CC0-DC80-4ABF-8871-998EE5D7BA32}' AND Value = 'MY FIELD NAME'
```

where

- `MY FIELD NAME` is a file type name

Comment: why do you use FieldId and value ? Why field Id is not enough ?

Comment: `{AB162CC0-DC80-4ABF-8871-998EE5D7BA32}` in this case is an id of **Type** field (Sitecore field), notice that query is executed agains `SharedFields` table not `Items`

Answer (score 3):

I used a variation of Balaji's answer to search for **data templates** that contain a particular field type (in this case "link"), rather than for content with the field type. This also pops up the results in SPE's nice data grid for printing as HTML or exporting to a spreadsheet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/templates" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Fields["{AB162CC0-DC80-4ABF-8871-998EE5D7BA32}"] -like "link"} | Show-ListView -Property FullPath, Id
```

Comment: good to know. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have powershell extension, you can try

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/content" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Fields["{AB162CC0-DC80-4ABF-8871-998EE5D7BA32}"] -like "Text"}
```

- 'Text' is a field type name

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to find templates utilizing a specific field type

```
$startPath = "master:/sitecore/templates/Features"
Write-Host "Search started $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$itemsToProcess = Get-ChildItem $startPath -Recurse

Write-Host "Items found: $($itemsToProcess.Count)"
if($itemsToProcess -ne $null) {
    $itemsToProcess | ForEach-Object { 
        $match = 0;

      
            if($_.Type -eq "General Link") {
              
                    $info = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        "ID"=$_.ID
                        "Path"=$_.Paths.FullPath
                        "Language"=$_.Language
                        "TemplateName"=$_.TemplateName
                        "FieldName"=$_.Name
                        "FieldType"=$_.Type
                    }
                    [void]$list.Add($info)
                
            }
    }
}
Write-Host "Search ended $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
Write-Host "Items found: $($list.Count)"
$list | Show-ListView
```

Replace $startPath with your path and replace the field type with what you need to find. In my example I was looking for a "General Link"